# PHP Calling a Function

Tags: php, functional-programming

How can I pass a function as a variable and then call it using that variable?

e.g.

```
test(echo);
function test($function)
{
    $function("Test");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just pass the function name as a string and it will work.

Note however that `echo` is *not* a function, so this does not work with `echo`.

Edit: Here's an example:

```
function my_function($x)
{
    echo $x;
}
function test($function)
{
    $function("Test");
}
test("my_function");
```

Answer (score 3):

You’re already on the right track with [variable functions](http://php.net/functions.variable-functions). But `echo` is a language construct and not a function:

> Variable functions won't work with language constructs such as `echo()`, `print()`, `unset()`, `isset()`, `empty()`, `include()`, `require()` and the like. Utilize wrapper functions to make use of any of these constructs as variable functions.

Besides that, the function would either be passed by its identifier:

```
test('function_name');
```

Or, in case of using [anonymous functions](http://php.net/functions.anonymous), by its value:

```
test(function() { /* … */ });
```

You should also take a look at [`is_callable`](http://php.net/is_callable) that can be used to test if the given parameter is callable.

Answer (score 0):

For a function like, say, substr, you can call a string with the value "substr":

```
$func = "substr";
$result = $func($string, 0, 10);
```

Eval can also be used:

```
$func = "substr";
$result = eval("return $func(\$string, 0, 10);");
```

Proceed with caution when using either of these. If $func is from user input, a malicious user could execute any function. Since PHP does not care too much (issues a warning) if you specify additional arguments, someone could, for example, execute "exec" with $string equal to "rm -rf /".

You can't do this with echo, because it is not a function; it is a language construct, like "if", or "while".